# UIActivityViewController completionHandler how to check if activity send or not successfully?

Tags: ios7, uiactivityviewcontroller, airdrop, completionhandler

I want to send one string via airdrop, I want to call one function when the String is received on other device successfully.  I had implemented it through UIActivityViewController and I check it via completionHandler.

Here is my scenario :
Device A ->send a string  To Device B
If Device B receive have two option  -> Accept or Decline
I want to call one function on Device A when Device B will receive or Decline that message.

Below is my implementation:

```
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[self.customURLContainer] applicationActivities:nil];

    activityViewController.completionHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
        NSLog(@"completed dialog - activity: %@ - finished flag: %d", activityType, completed);

        if ( completed )
        {
            NSLog(@"completionHandler - Succeed");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"completionHandler - didn't succeed.");
            // didn't succeed.
        }
```

But the above function always return 0, wether string is "Sent" or "Decline" by the other device.

Is it possible to check the on Device A? Because we can see the activity on Device A if receive than "Sent" and if Decline than "Declined".

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question? I mean to say, does it work now?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is currently not possible. You should file a [bug report](http://bugreporter.apple.com/) with Apple requesting this though

Comment: is this issue still true?