# UIActivityViewController Airdrop - Check the status when 'sent' or 'declined'

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, airdrop, uiactivitytypeairdrop

Is it possible to check if the recipient 'declined' or 'accepted' the share?

I want to NSLog 'sent' if sent and NSLog 'declined' if declined by the user.

Comment: Did you look into the `UIActivityViewControllerCompletionHandler`? Well, there is only a Bool value `completed`, but still, that more or less what you want, right?

Comment: Yes, I'm using that method. But for some reason, using AirDrop always returns '0'. Other services like message, mail return '0' and '1' as expected.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017017/uiactivityviewcontroller-completionhandler-how-to-check-if-activity-send-or-not