# Is it Correct / Possible to Explicitly Dismiss a UIActivityViewController (after AirDrop)?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, airdrop

In the screen shot below, some data has been successfully sent via *AirDrop*. The `UIActivityViewController` updates to show *"Sent"* under the recipient and *Cancel* is changed to *Done*.

[image]

- In this case, is it correct / good practice / possible, for the presenting view controller to dismiss the `UIActivityViewController`?
- Or should that task be left to the user (and the *Done* button)?

From Apple's docs on [`UIActivityViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIActivityViewController):

> Your app is responsible for configuring, presenting, **and dismissing** this view controller.

If the `UIActivityViewController` should be dismissed in the AirDrop case, should the completion handler be used for this purpose?

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) UIActivityViewControllerCompletionWithItemsHandler completionWithItemsHandler
```

Related questions:

- [UIActivityViewController completion handler is !completed when using AirDrop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26425077/uiactivityviewcontroller-completion-handler-is-completed-when-using-airdrop)
- [UIActivityViewController completionHandler how to check if activity send or not successfully?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017017/uiactivityviewcontroller-completionhandler-how-to-check-if-activity-send-or-not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further consideration of the documentation, and the flow of events when using either a built-in activity (e.g. `UIActivityTypeMail`) or a 3rd-party `UIActivity`, I think the following...

**1) AirDrop is a special case**, in that the user's interaction is performed within the `UIActivityViewController` itself. The UI in the `UIActivityViewController` updates accordingly, and the application should leave dismissing the `UIActivityViewController` to the user (and the *Cancel* / *Done* buttons).

**2) The completion handler is intended to be used *after* the `UIActivityViewController` has been dismissed**...

...and not for dismissing the `UIActivityViewController`.

To experiment, I added the following code:

```
[controller setCompletionWithItemsHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError) {
    NSLog(@"completed: %@, \n%d, \n%@, \n%@,", activityType, completed, returnedItems, activityError);

}];
```

- In the AirDrop case I get the log statement after tapping *Done* and the `UIActivityViewController` is dismissed (by the user) - not after the AirDrop action completes (and *"Sent"* is shown).
- If I use either a built-in activity (e.g. `UIActivityTypeMail`) or a custom, third party option, those actions (a) present additional UI and (b) result in the `UIActivityViewController` being dismissed, when the user finishes with that UI.

In both cases, I get the log statement after the `UIActivityViewController` is gone.

The documentation with regard to [*Accessing the Completion Handler*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIActivityViewControllerCompletionHandler) is actually quite clear:

> The completion handler to execute after the activity view controller is dismissed.

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) UIActivityViewControllerCompletionWithItemsHandler completionWithItemsHandler
```

> **Discussion**
>   When the user-selected service finishes operating on the data, or when the user dismisses the view controller, the view controller executes this completion handler to let your app know the final result of the operation.

I suppose it might have been more clear if this part:

> When the user-selected service finishes operating on the data...

indicated that the user-selected service finishing would result in the dismissal of the view controller.

**3) The following, from Apple's documentation on [UIActivityViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIActivityViewController) is a little misleading**:

> Your app is responsible for configuring, presenting, **and dismissing** this view controller.